# Python itertools combinations customizing

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am doing a question based on combinations and just stuck in it. And yes I am not so good in python.

The itertools combinations function using ncr just return the r possible combinations from n. I want something which will return the r possible combinations selected and also the other remaining elements from n numbers which were not selected in that iteration.

Example:

```
>>>from itertools import combinations
>>>list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>rslt = combinations(list, 2)
```

when `[2, 4]` is selected it should also return `[1, 3, 5]`
so it should return like `[[2, 4], [1, 3, 5]]`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.

You can use a list comprehension to get the other items `[j for j in l if j not in i]`:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in combinations(l,2):
    print(list(i),[j for j in l if j not in i])
```

And you will get :

```
[1, 2] [3, 4, 5]
[1, 3] [2, 4, 5]
[1, 4] [2, 3, 5]
[1, 5] [2, 3, 4]
[2, 3] [1, 4, 5]
[2, 4] [1, 3, 5]
[2, 5] [1, 3, 4]
[3, 4] [1, 2, 5]
[3, 5] [1, 2, 4]
[4, 5] [1, 2, 3]
```

---

By the way, it's not recommended to use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Does this can be done in one line list comprehension?

Comment: @Arman `[(list(i),[j for j in l if j not in i]) for i in combinations(l,2)]`

Comment: Thanks, will remember to not use that as variable name

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to make a copy of the original list, removing the elements that are in the combination:

```
from itertools import combinations
def combinations_and_remaining(l, n):
    for c in combinations(l, n):
        diff = [i for i in l if i not in c]
        yield c, diff 

for i in combinations_and_remaining([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
    print(i)
```

Will output

```
((1, 2), [3, 4, 5])
((1, 3), [2, 4, 5])
((1, 4), [2, 3, 5])
((1, 5), [2, 3, 4])
((2, 3), [1, 4, 5])
((2, 4), [1, 3, 5])
((2, 5), [1, 3, 4])
((3, 4), [1, 2, 5])
((3, 5), [1, 2, 4])
((4, 5), [1, 2, 3])
```

(The combinations returns tuples; remaining elements are returned as lists for efficiency)

Answer (score 1):

One slightly extravagant but fun way would be to use `combinations` twice:

```
from itertools import combinations
n = 5
k = 2
lst = list(range(1, n+1))
rslt = zip(combinations(lst, k), map(tuple, reversed(list(combinations(lst, n-k)))))
print(list(rslt))
# -> [((1, 2), (3, 4, 5)), ((1, 3), (2, 4, 5)), ((1, 4), (2, 3, 5)),
#     ((1, 5), (2, 3, 4)), ((2, 3), (1, 4, 5)), ((2, 4), (1, 3, 5)),
#     ((2, 5), (1, 3, 4)), ((3, 4), (1, 2, 5)), ((3, 5), (1, 2, 4)),
#     ((4, 5), (1, 2, 3))]
```

Comment: I think this is the only one here that works for inputs with duplicated elements

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loops and improve readability by using sets, as such:

```
from itertools import combinations

input = [1,2,3,4,5]

for n in itertools.combinations(input, 2):
    print(n , set(n) ^ set(input))
```

That is, of course, assuming there are no duplicates in the original, which will be lost in the conversion to a set.